# passing arguments to python script from command line

Tags: python, pandas

I am really new to python and pandas, I am trying to execute a python script using arguments in the command line but I got an error, here is my script

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 import sys, pandas as pd

 df1 = pd.read_table(sys.argv[0], sep="\t", header=0)
 df2 = pd.read_table(sys.argv[1], sep="\t", header=0)

 df_merge = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on=sys.arg[2],  right_on=sys.arg[3])
 df_merge.to_csv(sys.arg[4], sep="\t")
```

And I got the following error: `KeyError: u'no item named file.out'`, any help would be apreciated

My command line statement is: `merge_files.py file1.out file2.out col1 col3 test`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script, i.e. `merge_files.py`. You can see this by inserting `print(sys.argv)` at the beginning of your script. Try increasing all your indices by 1.

Answer (score 1):

The first argument `sys.argv[0]` is the name of the script.

> **sys.argv**:
>   The list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.
>   argv[0] is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether
>   this is a full pathname or not).

Please look [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.argv) for more details.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys, pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_table(sys.argv[1], sep="\t", header=0)
df2 = pd.read_table(sys.argv[2], sep="\t", header=0)

df_merge = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on=sys.arg[3],     right_on=sys.arg[4])
df_merge.to_csv(sys.arg[5], sep="\t")
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

increase all your indexes by 1, because `sys.argv[0]` - is a name of the python script.

I.e.

```
df1 = pd.read_table(sys.argv[1], sep="\t", header=0)
df2 = pd.read_table(sys.argv[2], sep="\t", header=0)
```

and so on